# URL rewriting not working with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to change URLs in one folder (`cartoon`) in my site to friendly SEO URLs.
This folder (`cartoon`) includes a PHP script not related to WordPress.

From:

```
example.com/cartoon/index.php?v=TitleEpisode
```

To:

```
example.com/cartoon/TitleEpisode
```

I read here all related questions but I did not benefit.

I have WordPress on my main domain (`example.com`).

I found this code in `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm parking-page.html

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's done.
i enter this after the first line in .htaccess

```
# BEGIN for Cartoon Folder
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?cartoon/(.+)$ /cartoon/?v=$1 [L,QSA]

# END for Cartoon Folder
```

thank u very much

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on the edit, it seems like what you want is for WordPress not to rewrite that slug but to ignore it.

You can do this by editing your `.htaccess` to exclude a folder. Make sure the folder is in the root directory of your site, as in, the same folder as `wp-admin`, `wp-content`, and `wp-includes`.

Then, open your `.htaccess` and add a rewrite rule to ignore that folder:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm parking-page.html

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Add this condition with the folder you want to ignore (cartoon in your example)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(cartoon|cartoon/.*)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Well, this is fairly open-ended. For a better answer, please edit the question to include what you have already tried. Also, what do you mean by "one folder"? Is this a custom post type? Is it a category or custom taxonomy? Are there different permalinks for different types/taxonomies? Please provide more details on what you want to do.

But for the usual case, here is the documentation for [pretty permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

First, make sure `URL Rewriting` is enabled in Apache. Example in Ubuntu/Debian

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now, in wp-admin, go to Settings -> Permalinks. Set the permalink to `Post Name`.

[image]

Then click save changes. It will either save the new `.htaccess` automatically if your site has the permissions to, or it will give you the new content of `.htaccess` to copy and paste.

Now you should be able to view a post or page and it should show the SEO-friendly links.

Answer (score 0):

How are you implementing (or intending to implement) the routing of `example.com/cartoon/TitleEpisode`?

If this is entirely outside of WordPress then I would expect you to have an additional `.htaccess` file inside the `/cartoon` subdirectory (since this is presumably a physical subdirectory)? This alone should be sufficient to override the WordPress mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file, since mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default.

For instance, simply enabling the `RewriteEngine` in a subdirectory is sufficient to override the WP directives.

In `/cartoon/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Then, in order to route a URL of the form `/cartoon/TitleEpisode` to `/cartoon/index.php?v=TitleEpisode`, you would need something like:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/]+) index.php?v=$1 [L]
```

(A bit similar to the WP directives in the parent `.htaccess` file.)

---

I would avoid editing between the `# BEGIN` and `# END WordPress` markers in the parent `.htaccess` file since these could be overridden by future WP updates.

You would instead implement an exception *before* the WP directives. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^cartoon - [L]
```

However, as mentioned above, you are probably better off creating an additional `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory and avoid touching the WordPress installation at all.